# Проверка существования каталога

Tags: java

Как проверить существует ли каталог?

Так можно проверить существование каталога или только существование файла?

```
File file = new File(filepath);
if (file.exists()) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Если директория уже существует, то она и не создастся. А так Files.exists(path)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проверить существование папки или файла можно следующим образом:

```
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
...
Path path = Paths.get("E:\\NecessaryFolder");

if (Files.exists(path)) {
    // действия, если папка существует
}
...
```

Прочитать об этом подробнее можно здесь: [docs.oracle.com](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html).
Аналогичный вопрос: [How to check if a folder exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15571496/how-to-check-if-a-folder-exists).
А также здесь: [клик](http://www.quizful.net/post/java-nio-tutorial).